# Is there no way to quickly copy/consolidate all files outside of project folder?

Tags: xcode

I've been dragging a few assets into my project in Xcode, and while I know you can check that box for 'copy items if needed', that doesn't always show up and so I end up with files that are located in scattered locations on my hard drive. I know I could manually put the files in the project folder, but is there no way to automatically copy external files to an internal location?

Comment: Unfortunately no there isn’t.

Comment: Is there any way to quickly view the locations of all files in the project? So I can check which ones are outside the actual project folder?

Comment: Yes, just view the project XML. That’s all it is, an XML file (well, a bundle of them actually).